# Quando o mysql_fecth_assoc, não acha, ele mata o resto do codigo, como fazer ele retornar algo?

Tags: php, funções, mysqli

Ola, estou com um problema nesta função ao deletar, faço uma busca do que será comparado, e coloco duas condição de delete, pois preciso que ele apague em uma condição duas tabelas, e se não houver nada na outra tabela, apague apenas uma, na minha simplicidade usei um `if`porém a busca quando ela não acha nenhum resultado na tabela, ela não executa o restante.

será que podem me ajudar

```
function deleta_pessoa_pg($conexao,$id){
        $id_valor = "SELECT viva.* from viagens_valor as viva where viva.id_pessoa = '$id'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $id_valor) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
        $listaitem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));     
        //echo $listaitem['id_pessoa'];


    if (!$listaitem['id_pessoa']) {
                //echo 'fala';
                $query2 = "DELETE FROM viagens WHERE id = '$id'";
                return mysqli_query($conexao, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
    }else{
                //echo 'oi';
                $query = "DELETE v.*, vv.* FROM viagens as v left JOIN viagens_valor as vv ON vv.id_pessoa = v.id WHERE v.id = '$id'";
                return mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Antes de mais nada, a o "viva*" do primeiro select está sem o ponto. Tem outros problemas no código, mas para comentar deles, precisaria entender o que quer fazer exatamente. Se seu IF depende de quantidades, tem que analisar o num_rows (ou affected_rows em outros casos que geram mudanças), e não se o fetch trouxe a primeira

Comment: Ola, a questão do código 'ponto' eu ja corrigi, vou explicar desde o começo do processo, vamos la: eu cadastro uma pessoa que ira viajar em uma tabela, e depois cadastro os valores que ela vem pagando, mas para apagar esta pessoa eu também preciso apagar os valores pagos por esta pessoa. ai então eu terei que apagar em duas tabelas ao mesmo, tempo, até ai tudo bem, porém quando eu precisar apagar só uma este comando de delete para as duas tabelas, não apaga só uma, e pra isso eu criei a consulta e o IF, e comparo o valor da consulta com o $ID que vem na 'function'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme citado pelo @Bacco você precisa usar uma contagem de registros para fazer isso. Tente fazer assim:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 0) {
                //echo 'fala';
                $query2 = "DELETE FROM viagens WHERE id = '$id'";
                return mysqli_query($conexao, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
    }
```

No exemplo acima, ele diz : "Se o numero de registros for igual a 0", ou seja, quando não há registros... entre nesta condição.

Não esqueça de apagar esses `or die(mysqli_error($conexao))` quando coloca-lo em produção.

Comment: valeu amigo @AndreiCoelho, mais uma vez vc me ajudou, obrigado mesmo, deu certo, não tinha pensado nesta situação, obrigado, deu certinho, acontecia que depois da $resultado, dava algum problema e ele não execultava o restante qndo não tinha valor, e desta forma, e ja faz a validação dentro do if, e dai de uma forma ou de outra ele  conclui. muito obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo @JuniorVenancio!